# How to selected which tags to print, instead of printing the whole tag list?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, tags, meta

When having this:

```
$tag_list = get_the_tag_list( '', ', ' );
```

I substituted the meta print:

```
printf(
$tag_list,
$category:list,
etc
);
```

by this:

```
$printArray_tag_list = explode(', ', $tag_list);
echo $category_list."/".$printArray_tag_list[0].','.$printArray_tag_list[1];
```

to print only the first two tags from the list (the first tags inserted, being this in Wordpress). Only then I realized that they are alphabetically ordered and those are not the tags I want to print.

Is there a way to print selected tags? Maybe selecting them in the custom fields?